# How do I make direct server calls and verify returned data in a Protractor test?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, jasmine, protractor

I have a Protractor test for my Angular application that signs up a new user, logs into the app and then deletes the account. My app doesn't currently have "delete account" functionality in its UI. However, it does have an API to delete users. I have the following test that works to delete an account.

```
var request = require('request');
...
describe('delete', function () {
    var jar, req;

    beforeEach(function () {
        jar = request.jar();
        req = request.defaults({
            jar: jar
        });
    });

    it('should delete account successfully', function () {
        req.post({
            json: true,
            url: constants.apiHostname() + '/api/v1/login/',
            form: {username: generatedEmail, password: password}
        }, function (error, message, body) {
            var userId = body.user.id;

            console.log("Deleting userId: " + userId);

            req.del(constants.apiHostname() + '/api/v1/users/' + userId, function (error, message, body) {
                console.log(message.statusCode);
            });
        });
    });
})
```

I'd like to be able to set expectations on the returned data. I tried adding the following just after the "var userId" line:

```
expect(userId).to.not.be(null);
```

When I do this, I get an error that there's no current spec:

```
/Users/mraible/dev/myapp/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasmine/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:792
        throw new Error('\'expect\' was used when there was no current spec, this could be because an asynchronous test timed out');
              ^
Error: 'expect' was used when there was no current spec, this could be because an asynchronous test timed out
    at Env.expect (/Users/mraible/dev/myapp/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasmine/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:792:15)
    at jasmineInterface.expect (/Users/mraible/dev/myapp/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasmine/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:2869:18)
    at global.expect (/Users/mraible/dev/myapp/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:151:10)
    at Request._callback (/Users/mraible/dev/myapp/tests/e2e/account.js:116:17)
```

Is it possible to call an API directly in a Protractor test and verify the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wander if it's because of they async nature of the request you are making, perhaps pass 'done' to the test function and call that after the expect within the callback? Something like:

```
it('should delete account successfully', function (done) {
        req.post({
            json: true,
            url: constants.apiHostname() + '/api/v1/login/',
            form: {username: generatedEmail, password: password}
        }, function (error, message, body) {
            var userId = body.user.id;
            expect(your expectation);
            done();
        });
    });
```

If that doesn't work, what is the output of body in the callback?

Comment: This worked - thanks Ben! To set an expectation in req.del, I had to pass 'done' as the second parameter. See my refactored test at https://gist.github.com/mraible/4c01f5ad60e7d7cb6ffb.